# Accessing panels with similar names

Tags: c#, winforms, names, panels

I am making some game where I have lots of panels. Their names are polje1, polje2, polje3 etc ... For some of them, I need to call Invalidate() method to refresh the paint event and problem is that I don't want to use 50 ifs or switch function.

So, can I do something like `("polje" + number).Invalidate();`

Here is some code if you don't understand:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
private Panel polje1;
private Panel polje2;
private Panel polje3;
private Panel polje4;
private Panel polje5;
private Panel polje6;
private Panel polje7;
private Panel polje8;
private Panel polje9;
private Panel polje10;

definition bla bla bla
...

private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int pp = rnd.Next(1,7);
  SetCurrentField(pp);
  ("polje" + pp).Invalidate();
```

}

Neither Invalidate() method only is not an option, because form is flickering ! I already make my class and perform DoubleBuffered();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a control by it's name property through the container's control collection:

Example showing the ContainsKey function to make sure the control's name does exist in the collection:

```
Panel polje1 = new Panel() { Name = "polje1" };
this.Controls.Add(polje1);
if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("polje1")) {
  this.Controls["polje1"].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```